# Function that uses functions as parameters

Tags: python, function

I am trying to evaluate the following type of expression

```
max(0,x_2-1)
```

for an interval of values of `x_2`.

The final objective is to be able to obtain a plot of an expression of the form

```
max(0,x_2-1) >= max(x_1,x_3-1)
```

I don't think python has any built in function to do this, so I was trying to write my own function but I am not sure how to write a function that has another function, like `x_2-1`, as input.

Could anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: You can pass functions as parameters to other functions in the same way as you would pass anything else: `def foo(f): print(f(2))`, `def bar(x): return x*2`, `foo(bar)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are objects in python:

```
def foo(x, fxn):
    return fxn(x) + 5

def bar(x):
    return x + 10

print(foo(2, bar))
```

prints `17`